# app with paypal ios sdk. sandbox and live credentials?

Tags: ios, paypal, credentials

am doing my sandbox testing with developer credentials. when i want to go live, should I (developer) get business account and thereby live credentials? if i develop an app for someone, why can't i have other person who has a business create paypal account (on developer.paypal.com??) and get live credentials? then use those credentials in app. as a developer i can submit the app to paypal and manage it. but i don't want to create premier business account.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/

above doc says:

"All calls to PayPal operations are made through the application account, which is a PayPal account that is controlled by the application owner. ...To obtain live PayPal credentials, you must have a verified Premier or verified Business PayPal account."
:
:
"
Log in to the PayPal Developer website using the credentials of the PayPal account registered to the application owner.
Note that the PayPal account associated with the application must be a verified Premier or verified Business account."

could someone clarify?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop/test a couple different ways....

1. You can have your merchant that you are developing for login to dev portal, create the app, and then provide you with their test credentials.  This way when you go Live, they just need to enable their Live credentials, provide them to you, and then you can swap the test credentials out for the Live ones.
2. You can develop/test with your app you created in your developer portal and your test credentials.  When you want to go Live then you would need the merchant to go into their dev portal, create an app, enable their Live credentials, and then have them provide those credentials to you.

The first way is going to be less of a headache for you (in my opinion) because then you will be testing with the same App from development to Live.  Also, this way you know that the App has been created and the merchant can enable their Live credentials while you are developing/testing versus waiting for them to do all of that when you are ready to go Live.

Comment: Sounds good. As long as I could replace test credentials of mine with live credentials of merchant then that should be fine. Option 1 would work too. thanks.